# How can I remove a tub spout with a stripped hex bolt/machine screw?

Tags: bathroom

I have a slip on tub spout with a stripped hex nut. I need to remove it but I don't think it is wise to use the traditional method (drill into the bolt, hammer in an extractor,etc) put the space is very small.

So, I think the best method is to use snips and cut off the spout, then cut off the plastic seal assembly to remove the hex bolt with a pliers or something.

thoughts? alternatives?

Comment: Have you tried twisting/pulling?  They typically are just held on with that one little bolt, you can probably get it off with a bit of muscle

Comment: i have. But, i'm concerned that I might mess the soldered elbow joints inside the wall. I'm not sure how much elbow grease to use. fixing broken solder would be a gigantic job.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the inside of the hex nut is stripped so that the allen wrench turns within the nut...

Get a spare allen wrench and a replacement set screw and a small tube of epoxy glue.  Dab the glue on the end of the wrench and insert it into the nut.  Hold in place while the glue sets.  Unscrew the nut.

Discard the now fused nut/wrench combo and replace with new set screw using new allen wrench.

Comment: that's awesome. thanks. I'll try that tonight.

Comment: That didn't work. Thanks for the idea, i'm going to remember that for another time. I actually had to cut the spout off with snips and then use a wrench to loosen the bolt. I way over-tightened it and stripped it. Time consuming but a good lesson learned :)

Comment: Sorry it wasn't of more help!